# Do i need a core data migration when i add a new model to my .xcdatamodeld file

Tags: ios, core-data-migration

i have a an .xcdatamodeld which already has 2 entities, i have added another entity into this file(am not sure whether this is the right way to add a new entity), anyways my question is, do i need to implement any kind of migrations to take care of users who already have the app installed on their devices.

Please note, i have not modified any columns or schema on already existing entities.

cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to do migration if you just only adding new entity, assuming that it doesn't have relationship with the other. According to [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/114084/core-data-migrations-tutorial-lightweight-migrations), you have to do migration for the following scenario:

1. Deleting entities, attributes or relationships.
2. Renaming entities, attributes or relationships using the renamingIdentifier.
3. Adding a new, optional attribute.
4. Adding a new, required attribute with a default value.
5. Changing an optional attribute to non-optional and specifying a default value.
6. Changing a non-optional attribute to optional.
7. Changing the entity hierarchy.
8. Adding a new parent entity and moving attributes up or down the hierarchy.
9. Changing a relationship from to-one to to-many.
10. Changing a relationship from non-ordered to-many to ordered to-many (and vice versa).

Comment: thanks a lot, for this response am doing some testing (simulating the installation of an updated version with the new entity) just to verify that everything works fine, then i will mark this as the correct answer